# How to Solve parameter error in Strored Procedure call in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a stored Procedure in my DB like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Getit()
BEGIN
SELECT title 
FROM course 
WHERE description="just a course";
END //
```

Now In the spring boot App I am calling this method like this:

```
public interface coursesdao extends JpaRepository<course, Integer>{
    
    @Procedure
    String Getit();
}
```

and Later this:

```
public String getprocedure() {
        return cdao.Getit();
    }
```

I am getting a error like this:

`Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter.`

but I have no parameters to pass to the procedure.How can I solve it?

Comment: Your stored proc comes back a resultset, but you are calling it like a function. It does not have a return value, the resultsets are passed to the calling application through a different method

Comment: Got the solution,Thanks for the tip anyways

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution,Its working now!

Just tweaked the Procedure a little bit like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Getitout(OUT output VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT title into output
FROM course 
WHERE description="just a course";
END //
```